# Derivative of function of matrix vector product

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Suppose we have

$$ f(W) = g(Wx) $$

with $g:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $W \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I know that the Jacobian w/r/t $W$ is:

$$ J_{W} (f) = x J_{(Wx)}(g)$$

One can derive this using elementwise reasoning. However, I find this confusing because the "typical case" is that the Jacobian of a composition is just the successive multiplication of Jacobians in the same order as written in the composition. For example:

$$ J_{x} (g(Wx)) = J_{(Wx)}(g)W$$

I have to use formulations like this alot, and I have taken to more or less "memorizing" the reversed order of $J_W(f)$ as a special case -- even though I could re-derive it, it sticks out as nonintuitive.

I have a notion that this might be explainable either using tensor products or using differentials (and indeed that if tensor products are used, we could somehow show that the Jacobian *tensor* is being left multiplied). But I'm not sure how to proceed, even after consulting Wikipedia and the Matrix Cookbook.

Without reasoning on an element-by-element basis, how could you derive $J_W(f)$ and explain the apparently puzzling "swap" in order relative to the "usual" case?

Comment: Is $g$ scalar valued?

Comment: Yes. Updated to clarify, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be a little careful here, linear functions on matrices cannot always be written as a straight matrix multiplication.

Use linear approximations. This is how I think of derivatives.

$g(x+h) -g(x) \approx Dg(x)(h)$.

Then $f(W+H)-f(W) = g(Wx+Hx)-g(Wx) \approx Dg(Wx)(Hx)$.

From this we conclude $Df(W)(H) = Dg(Wx)(Hx)$.

This is straightforward to formalise.

Alternatively, note that $ f = g \circ h$, where $h(W) = Wx$.
Then $Df(W)=Dg(h(W))Dh(W)$, and
$D h(W)(H) = Hx$. Expanding gives
$Df(W)(H)= Dg(Wx)Hx$.

Comment: Thank you -- how should I interpret $Dg(x)(h)$? For example, what kind of object is $Dg(x)$? A linear transformation? Sorry to be so basic.

Comment: If $g:A \to B$, then $Dg(a):A \to B$. $Dg(a)$ is a linear transformation from $A$ to $B$. The only catch here is that the parameter to $f$ is a matrix, not the usual element of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or whatever field).

Comment: If $g$ is scalar valued, and one uses the inner product induced by the Frobenius norm, then you can write $\nabla f(W) = Dg(Wx)^T x^T$. Remember $Dg(a)$ is a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$, that is a row vector.

Comment: Note that since the gradient is given by the previous comment, there is some justification in saying that $Jf(W) = x Jg(Wx)$, but I think it is misleading, as you really need to be thinking of the scalar valued map $H \mapsto Dg(Wx)Hx$.

Comment: I think I'm stuck on the "straightforward" part :-)   I understand the equality, but how do we reason from $Df(W)(H) = Dg(Wx)(Hx)$ to the matrix form of $J_W(f)$ (or its transpose, not particular about which we choose)? Where does the outer product come in? (Ultimately the matrix form is important because it's part of a numerical calculation on a computer.) I will dig a little more into the "inner product" formulation when I have a bit more time; at the moment I don't quite follow that approach.

Comment: Well, it doesn't really have a 'nice' 'matrix' form. It is a map $\mathbb{R}^{m \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, and cannot be written as $H \mapsto HA$ for some $A$. It does have the form $H \mapsto a^T H b$. (It does take some time to become familiar with the notation.) (By straightforward are you referring to formalising the above?)

Comment: The 'inner product' representation comes from $a^T Hb = \operatorname{tr} (a^THb) = \operatorname{tr} (b a^T H) = \operatorname{tr} ((a b^T)^T H)$.

Comment: I feel like I'm being dense. Isn't the derivative of a scalar-valued function with respect to a matrix, an identically shaped matrix? Are you saying that that is true, but we can't do the usual trick of transposing the derivative to get the Jacobian because the linear approximation does not admit a matrix form?

Comment: No, if $f: A \to B$ then the derivative evaluated at a point of $a$ is a linear operator $Df(a): A \to B$. In this case, $A = \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$ and $B = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23525/discussion-between-mike-kayser-and-copper-hat).

Comment: Well, I try to avoid explicit partial derivative calculation as I get lost in the detail, so I prefer to work as above.

Comment: I've looked at this again and I think I understand it, but I have one more question. In the step from $Dg(Wx)(Hx)$ to $\operatorname{tr}(Dg(Wx)Hx)$ it seems you have recast a function application as a multiplication and in so doing, reinterpreted $Dg(Wx)$ as a row vector. I can see why this works here because $Dg(Wx)$ is $\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. Is that precisely the reason why you can step from the linear functional statement to the matrix statement? Once you're there I see how the trace invariance allows you to construct the gradient.

Comment: Well, if $ABC$ happens to be a scalar quantity, then $ABC = \operatorname{tr}(ABC)$. A property of trace is that you can cycle the argument, so $\operatorname{tr}(ABC) = \operatorname{tr}(CAB)$ ($CAB$) is not necessarily a scalar). This is so it can be written in the form $\operatorname{tr}(D^T B) $ or $\langle D,B \rangle$.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did catch that any scalar is also the trace of that scalar, and that you can cyclically permute the arguments. My question is more precisely about the step $Dg(Wx)(Hx) = Dg(Wx)Hx$, which changes a function application to a multiplication and a linear transformation to a row vector. All I mean to ask is: is it accurate to say that this step is permitted because all $\mathbb{R^n} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ linear transformations can be represented by a row vector? Oh, I guess this is the Riesz representation theorem.

Comment: That works because $\gamma=Dg(Wx)$ is a row vector, so $\gamma Hx$ is a scalar (the linear function here is $H \mapsto \gamma Hx$).

Comment: OK, got it. Thanks!!